# Re-position windows when going from two screens to one

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

So long story short, at work I use my MacBook Pro and I connect it to another, bigger monitor. I use a shared screen setup so I can drag windows back and forth between the two monitors, but when I get home I use the Mac by itself, with no external display.

When I leave work, I never really turn off my MacBook Pro. I just disconnect the cable that connects the laptop to the monitor, close the Mac, and leave.

The problem is that when I get home and open the Mac, the windows that were on the external monitor while at work now are off-screen. (I can for example see a tiny bit of the side of the window, so it is hard to grab said window to move it into the middle of my laptop's internal display.)

Is there a way/setting/method so that when I disconnect the second screen, everything that was on the external screen moves fully to the MacBook Pro screen?

For example on my home workstation, I run a 3 monitor Windows setup and as soon as any of those are disconnected, all that monitor's assets are shifted to the main screen. I'm wondering if apple has anything similar.

**EDIT**: another thing that's a bit annoying is that if I enlarged a window on the bigger monitor and drag it from the side to the center when going from 2 screens to 1, I sometimes have to resize with the resize handle on the bottom-right. When that's off-screen, I have to close the window and reopen it.